CSC909DB chip, how to get unlimited power delivery
I would like to repurpose disposable vape components (battery cell + PCB) to power my shaver (and so get ride of dead NiMH battery).

PCB is fitted with a CSC909DB chip (spec sheet: http://www.cschip.com/upload/cn/propdf/CSC909X.pdf).
Theses infos are from:

the floppydisk question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/120881/floppydisk), Help identifying the chip from the photo, URL (version: 2023-05-21): Help identifying the chip from the photo

https://www.elektronik-labor.de/Notizen/Dampfer.html


I remove the pressure trigger and replace it with a switch, but after several secs, the power is cut due to long-time smoking protection*****.
Do you know which component is used to define the time duration before long-time smoking protection? A capacitor? I tried to find PCB schematic example for this CSC909DB chip w/o success.
*****Optional 10/5/7.5/12.5 seconds long-time smoking protection; undervoltage protection threshold 3.1V;

can you just use the cell and replace the charge controller with one that behaves as you require? They can be had for less than a few $USD. I don't see an old-fashioned timing circuit you could "Bend", so it's probably all done via the micro, which is far more complex to reprogram (looking at >4 hours of hacking) than to replace.

Tks @dandavis , yes it's my plan B : using a usb-c charge controller with a T4056 chip. As battery capacity i'll used is smaller than 18650 cells (around 800mAh), i have to swap a resistor to reduce charge current. In the T4056 datasheet, charge current definition is done thanks to a resistance value put btw the PROG pin and the ground. So i was thinking maybe the CSC909DB has similar implementation to define the time duration before long-time smoking protection
